# Create text file and make it hidden and readOnly c#

Tags: c#, text-files

How to Create text file and make it's Properties Hidden and Archive and ReadOnly using C#?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
FileStream fs = File.Create("test.txt");
fs.Close();
File.SetAttributes(
   "test.txt", 
   FileAttributes.Archive | 
   FileAttributes.Hidden | 
   FileAttributes.ReadOnly
   );
```